# Problema con autenticacion MySql WorkBench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

estaba trabajando en una app que se conecta a mysql server como base de datos pero en algun momento cambie la contraseña del usuario *root* ahora cuando intento ver los datos en mis tablas me aparece esto 10:52:23 : Error Code: 1820 You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.

entiendo lo que dice peor no conozco al sintaxis para hacerlo alguien puede ayudarme si la conoce?

Comment: Tienes que realizar los pasos indicados en el sitio de mysql. [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html]